# CSV breaks up values on non delimeter

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read mixed CSV fields, where there are quoted fields and non-quoted numerical with the following :

```
from csv import reader

bar = """1234,"abc,def","dasd",341234234"""
foo = reader(bar)
[x for x in foo]
```

this returns

```
[['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['', ''], ['abc,def'], ['', ''], ['dasd'], ['', ''], ['3'], ['4'], ['1'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4'], ['2'], ['3'], ['4']]
```

I tried using
foo = reader(bar, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')

But it still breaks up numbers. I basically need to read csv.QUOTE_NONNUMERIC
from writer, but it is not reading it properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

csv reader works on file objects. Here is what you could do

```
from csv import reader
import StringIO

bar = """1234,"abc,def","dasd",341234234"""
f = StringIO.StringIO(bar)
foo = reader(f,  delimiter=',')
print [x for x in foo]
```

This will give you o/p

```
[['1234', 'abc,def', 'dasd', '341234234']]
```

Hope that works for you.

Comment: i figured it is has something to do with input but wasnt sure that it is this strict with types